# Text 'guesser' / tumbler like animation

Tags: javascript, strings, animation

I made a tumbler thingy...
Do you see possible bugs in the code or any improvements I could do?

```js
var text = "0000 ASCII (Listeni/ˈæski/ ass-kee), abbreviated from American Standard Code for Information Interchange,[1] is a character-encoding scheme (the IANA prefers the name US-ASCII[2]). ASCII codes represent text in computers, communications equipment, and other devices that use text. Most modern character-encoding schemes are based on ASCII, though they support many additional characters. ASCII was the most common character encoding on the World Wide Web until December 2007, when it was surpassed by UTF-8, which includes ASCII as a subset.[3][4][5]";

// Returns a random integer between min and max.
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function tumbler(text) {
  var length = text.length;
  var tumbleText = "";

  function tumble() {
    var code, i, newTumbleText = "",
      rand;

    // Test if we're done.
    if (text === tumbleText) {
      return document.body.style.color = "white";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      // Compare the two chars.
      if (text[i] !== tumbleText[i]) {
        code = text.charCodeAt(i);
        rand = getRandomInt(code - 10 < 0 ? 0 : code - 10, code + 10);
        newTumbleText += String.fromCodePoint(rand);
      } else {
        newTumbleText += text[i];
      }
    }

    tumbleText = newTumbleText;
    document.body.textContent = tumbleText;
    window.setTimeout(tumble, 60);
  }

  tumble();
}

tumbler(text);
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: lime;
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
}
```

Comment: The demo would be so much cooler if it were in a monospace font.

Comment: @200_success I made one that does the entire page [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oa17b1nq/) (just paste it in console). Let's try monofont next indeed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeated string concatenation is not recommended, since strings are immutable.  You should use an array of characters instead, and perform one join at the end.

Since your random number generator is not really retrieving anything, I'd rename `getRandomInt()` to just `randomInt()`.  I would hide the function as a helper inside the `tumbler()` function.  The convention in JavaScript is to use inclusive lower bounds and exclusive upper bounds.  (See `String.substring(start, end)`, for example.)  To establish the lower bound for the call, I would use `Math.max()` instead of the ternary expression.

I don't like to see lots of variable declarations up front, especially when I have no idea what these variables mean.

> ```
> var code, i, newTumbleText = "",
>   rand;
> ```

It would be better to declare them at the point of use, and use `'use strict'` to ensure that all variables are properly declared.

If you use `font-family: monospace` and ensure that spaces are preserved rather than randomized, then the animation would look less erratic.

```js
var text = "0000 ASCII (Listeni/ˈæski/ ass-kee), abbreviated from American Standard Code for Information Interchange,[1] is a character-encoding scheme (the IANA prefers the name US-ASCII[2]). ASCII codes represent text in computers, communications equipment, and other devices that use text. Most modern character-encoding schemes are based on ASCII, though they support many additional characters. ASCII was the most common character encoding on the World Wide Web until December 2007, when it was surpassed by UTF-8, which includes ASCII as a subset.[3][4][5]";
tumbler(text);

function tumbler(text) {
  'use strict';
  var buffer = new Array(text.length);
  tumble();

  // Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive).
  function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }

  function tumble() {
    var done = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
      if (text[i] === ' ') {
        buffer[i] = ' ';
      } else if (text[i] !== buffer[i]) {
        var code = text.charCodeAt(i);
        var rand = randomInt(Math.max(0, code - 10), code + 11);
        buffer[i] = String.fromCodePoint(rand);
        done = false;
      }
    }
    
    if (done) {
      document.body.style.color = "white";
    } else {
      document.body.textContent = buffer.join('');
      window.setTimeout(tumble, 60);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: lime;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look tomorrow. Here's a [bookmarklet version](https://jsfiddle.net/oa17b1nq/2/) of this effect for your troubles ;)

Comment: Nice changes you did there. The buffer and `Math.max` are much better indeed, and I also like the optimization you did to `done`. Bonus points for keeping the spaces, it looks better.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty fun little bit of code. Very neatly written as well. Only thing I would suggest would be to use .charAt(x) instead of using array indexers for your strings when you're comparing characters. Not a big deal but will improve compatibility among browsers and is a bit easier to read IMHO.

```
// Compare the two chars.
if (text.charAt(i) !== tumbleText.charAt(i))
```

Good stackoverflow post covers it in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051385/javascript-access-string-chars-as-array).